# What is the difference between a dπ-dπ and delta bond

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, bond, coordination-compounds, organometallic-compounds

I have always been wondering the difference between a dπ-dπ bond and a delta bond. What are the situations that either bond is formed in overlap of two d orbitals.

Comment: Why, it's really simple: dπ-dπ has one nodal plane along the bond, while $\delta$ has two.